# INSERT INTO SELECT not working

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert-into

I need help inserting a few selected columns from table1 into another table2 (with a WHERE clause). The columns that I want to insert are the same in both tables. But, each table has other columns that are not in the other table. For example, table2 has a column called 'neighborhood', which is not in table1. I want to grab nid, ccn, reportdatetime, latitude, longitude, event_type from table1 and put it in table2, and the 'neighborhood' column for this new row should be null.

This is my MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO table2 
SELECT nid, ccn, reportdatetime, latitude, longitude, event_type 
FROM table1 
WHERE nid=943662
```

I'm getting this error:

```
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Name the columns you're inserting into:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (nid, ccn, reportdatetime, latitude, longitude, event_type) 
SELECT nid, ccn, reportdatetime, latitude, longitude, event_type 
FROM table1 
WHERE nid=943662;
```

This will cause nulls to be inserted into columns that aren't explicitly named

Comment: This should be the solution.  The problem is that table2 columns have a different number of columns than table1, and therefore it's throwing that exception.

By using the above query, you're forcing the column counts to be equal.

Comment: @Magnum You're mistaken. This query will work no matter how many columns are in table2, as long as the unnamed columns are nullable.

Comment: @Bohemian, Thanks so much for the help. It worked! I forgot the bit in the parentheses. Have a great weekend.